# I want to convert a resultset to a string. I have tried everything but it always gives no data found. Please provide some solution

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to convert a `ResultSet` to a string. I have tried everything but it always gives no data found. Please provide some solution

Comment: Show us what you have tried (the code) and the exact error message.

Comment: we tried everything and couldn't figure out what's your code

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount;) {
        builder.append(resultSet.getString(i + 1));
        if (++i < columnCount) builder.append(",");
    }
    builder.append("\r\n");
}
String resultSetAsString = builder.toString();
```

You may need to tweak the string format a *bit* more to suit your needs. Alternatively, you can also map the `ResultSet` to a collection of Javabeans whose class has the `Object#toString()` overriden.

E.g.

```
public class Row {
    private Long id;
    private String columnName1;
    private String columnName2;
    // Add/generate constructors, getters and setters.

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Row[id=%d,columName1=%s,columnName2=%s", id, columnName1, columnName2);
    }
}
```

with

```
List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    Row row = new Row();
    row.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
    row.setColumnName1(resultSet.getString("columnName1"));
    row.setColumnName2(resultSet.getString("columnName2"));
    rows.add(row);
}

// To display it:
for (Row row : rows) {
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

As to your *actual* problem (you apparently got an exception with the words "no data found"), you'll need to provide the stacktrace and the code snippet which caused this, so that you'll get better suited answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with overriding `toString()` method and implement the returned `String` as you like.

Comment: How do you do it for ResultSet unless you are implementing driver?

Comment: Perhaps wrap the resultSet in a new instance of _some_ ResultSetImpl

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say with no code, but if you're trying to retrieve the data in the "tx_content" field, try getting "TX_CONTENT" - sometimes upper/lower case makes a difference.