# How to convert ResultSet to string in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to convert resultset to string. After that, I will use the string to write a html file.Course is a table contain courseid(String),name(String),prerequisites(String) connect database is ok. Here is my code and idea. Can you evaluate my idea or give me some better solution?

```
private static void printRecordFromCourse() throws SQLException {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String printSQL = "SELECT * FROM course";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(printSQL);
        while(rs.next()){
            //Retrieve by column name
            String courseid  = rs.getString("courseid");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String prerequisites = rs.getString("prerequisites");

            String result+ = "<tr><td>"+courseid+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+prerequisites"</td></tr>";
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some error that you are getting with the above code? You can use a class - Course and use corresponding getter/setter methods to access/update the values

Comment: no I mean how to convert the resultset rs into String. My program work nỏmally

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317251/i-want-to-convert-a-resultset-to-a-string-i-have-tried-everything-but-it-always

Comment: I wont recommend you calling toString directly on resultset. You should populate it in your Course class and define custom toString in your Course class which you can then call toString upon. Please ensure you add java tag to your question.

Comment: A ResultSet isn't a string, or anything resembling one. Logically speaking it is an array of maps. You need to traverse it, getting column values for each row, and do whatever you need to do with those.

Comment: Ok I got it thanks all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Resultset to String array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106914/convert-resultset-to-string-array)

Answer (score 5):

You could use an ArrayList and store the columns in there, such as:

```
List allRows = new ArrayList();
    while(rs.next()){
        String[] currentRow = new String[numberColumns];
        for(int i = 1;i<=numberColumns;i++){
            row[i-1]=rs.getString(i);
        }
        rows.add(row);
    }
```

Your ArrayList now contains String arrays, where each array represents one row. Now you can simply transform the string array entries into strings, e.g. using `Arrays.toString(allRows.get(i));`

Comment: How can you have a dynamic numberColumns?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried your code, but it looks workable at a glance.

Design-wise, we usually want to separate database access from other logic.

And likely you will want to define a class `Course` to hold this data and your business logic that operates on that data. For example, you may choose to implement a `toHtmlTableRow` method on `Course` that generates the HTML source. (In a more complex or sophisticated environment, you might also want to move that HTML-generation functionality to another class.) Something like this:

```
class Course {
    String id, name, prereq;

    public Course ( String id , String name , String prereq ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.prereq = prereq;
    }

    public CharSequence toHtmlTableRow () {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.append( "<tr>\n" );
        html.append( "<td>" + this.id + "</td><td>" + this.name + "</td><td>" + this.prereq + "</td>\n" );
        html.append( "</tr>\n" );
        return html;
    }

    // Override `Object`.
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Course{ " +
        "id='" + id + '\'' +
        " | name='" + name + '\'' +
        " | prereq='" + prereq + '\'' +
        " }";
    }
}
```

Here is a complete working example app. For the sake of this demo, I crammed it all into a single `.java` file. In real work, I would not.

This example uses the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). This example makes an in-memory database that never gets written to storage, again because this is a mere example.

Note the use of the [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) & [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) syntax found in newer versions of Java to simplify working with JDBC.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class DbToText {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        DbToText app = new DbToText();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt () {

        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List< Course > courses = new ArrayList();

        try (
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:db_to_text" ) ;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE course_ ( \n" +
            "  id_ VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
            "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
            "  prereq_ VARCHAR NOT NULL \n" +
            ");";
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO course_ ( id_ , name_ , prereq_ ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? ) ;";
            try (
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
            ) {
                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , "C01" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 2 , "Course 1" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , "None" );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , "C02" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 2 , "Course 2" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , "C01" );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , "C03" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 2 , "Course 3" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , "C02" );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM course_";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    String id = rs.getString( "id_" );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    String prereq = rs.getString( "prereq_" );

                    // Instantiate a `Course` object for this data.
                    Course c = new Course( id , name , prereq );
                    courses.add( c );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "List of courses: \n" + courses );

        System.out.println( "Courses as HTML table rows: " );
        for ( Course course : courses ) {
            System.out.println( course.toHtmlTableRow() );
        }
    }

    class Course {
        String id, name, prereq;

        public Course ( String id , String name , String prereq ) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.prereq = prereq;
        }

        public CharSequence toHtmlTableRow () {
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            html.append( "<tr>\n" );
            html.append( "<td>" + this.id + "</td><td>" + this.name + "</td><td>" + this.prereq + "</td>\n" );
            html.append( "</tr>\n" );
            return html;
        }

        // Override `Object`.
        @Override
        public String toString () {
            return "Course{ " +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            " | name='" + name + '\'' +
            " | prereq='" + prereq + '\'' +
            " }";
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
List of courses: 
[Course{ id='C01' | name='Course 1' | prereq='None' }, Course{ id='C02' | name='Course 2' | prereq='C01' }, Course{ id='C03' | name='Course 3' | prereq='C02' }]
Courses as HTML table rows: 
<tr>
<td>C01</td><td>Course 1</td><td>None</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>C02</td><td>Course 2</td><td>C01</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>C03</td><td>Course 3</td><td>C02</td>
</tr>
```